# WebApi 2.2 basecontroller with endpoints that can be overridden keeping routing

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-web-api2

I am having some trouble with webapi 2.2 routing. I have installed v5.2 into my project and have modified my config to use a Custom DirectRouteProvider

```
public class CustomDirectRouteProvider : DefaultDirectRouteProvider
        {
            protected override IReadOnlyList<IDirectRouteFactory>
            GetActionRouteFactories(HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
            {
                return actionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<IDirectRouteFactory>
                (inherit: true);
            }
        }
```

Now I have setup a base controller with methods that I want to allow to be overridden for example

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    [EnableQuery]
    public async virtual Task<IHttpActionResult> Get()
    {
        var data = await DomainService.GetQueryable();
        if (data != null)
        {
           return Ok(data);
        }
        return NotFound();

    }
```

If I run the project and call an endpoint like `http://localhost:3000/somecontroller` the above Get() method is called.
If within somecontroller I try

```
    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery]
    [Route("")]
    public async override Task<IHttpActionResult> Get()
    {

        var data = await _skillRepository.ParentSkillsAsync();
        if (data != null)
        {
            return Ok(data);
        }
        return NotFound();
    }
```

I get an error of

> Multiple actions were found that match the request

Is there anyway to do what I am trying here? is frustrating trying to get this to work.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dan - I was having the same trouble myself and here's how I solved it.
I'm not sure if this is the best solution, but it's working for me.

On my route attribute I added the Order property with a value of 3 into the action on the base class.
The default value for the Order property is 0, so the value of the derived class would be 0.
The base class needs to have an Order property that is higher than the derived class.

So, in your example, I believe this would allow your code to work like you want it to:

Action in base class

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("", Order=3)]
[EnableQuery]
public async virtual Task<IHttpActionResult> Get()
{
    var data = await DomainService.GetQueryable();
    if (data != null)
    {
       return Ok(data);
    }
    return NotFound();
}
```

Action in derived class:

```
[HttpGet]
[EnableQuery]
[Route("")]
public async override Task<IHttpActionResult> Get()
{
    var data = await _skillRepository.ParentSkillsAsync();
    if (data != null)
    {
        return Ok(data);
    }
    return NotFound();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Shane!!!! I have been stuck on that one for ages. I did try the order attribute earlier however I had them around the wrong way. Base was set to 0 and I was trying the derived as 1. doh!

Comment: @DriverDan you are very welcome.  I just happened to be trying to solve this very thing this last weekend.  I actually did the same thing my first time around.  The documentation I initially read didn't tell me in what order it was processed, but then reading this in detail gave it clarity - [asp.net webapi2 action routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) - look all the way to the bottom and the Route Order area.